# Rotating a globe before FlyingTo a location in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox's FlyTo like this example:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
center: [-74.5, 40],
zoom: 4
});
 
document.getElementById('fly').addEventListener('click', () => {
// Fly to a random location
map.flyTo({
center: [(Math.random() - 0.5) * 360, (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100],
essential: true // this animation is considered essential with respect to prefers-reduced-motion
});
});
```

It works just like the example [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto/), with a button to trigger it, and locations loaded from a json file. What I want to achieve is that, before the map.flyTo, to do at least two full rotates really fast to simulate a spinning of a physical globe, and then go to the first location, then clicking the button again, does a full spin again (don't know if its possible to zoom out before this), and goes to the next location etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Tried some solutions online but they end up spinning the globe indefinitely..